# mock file open in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

I'm trying to mock file open, and all of the examples show that I need to

```
@patch('open', create=True)
```

but I keep getting

```
Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'open'
```

I know patch needs the **full dotted path of `open`**, but I have no idea what it is. As a matter of fact, I'm not even sure that's the problem.

Comment: 1. From what you've posted, we cannot tell you what the path should be, or if that's the problem. Give a [mcve]. 2. You know there's [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) specifically for this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to include a module name; if you are testing in a script, the name of the module is `__main__`:

```
@patch('__main__.open')
```

otherwise use the name of the module that contains the code you are testing:

```
@patch('module_under_test.open')
```

so that any code that uses the `open()` built-in will find the patched global instead.

Note that the `mock` module comes with a [`mock_open()` utility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) that'll let you build a suitable `open()` call with file data:

```
@patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data='foo\nbar\nbaz\n'))
```

Comment: A question further: Could such a mock (with specified return_value) be used as a context manager (within a `with` statement)?

Comment: @0xc0de: yes, the documenation I link to includes examples of `open()` being used with a `with` statement and being patched with `mock_open()`.

Comment: Yes, I saw it later, after asking here. Thanks.

Comment: A further question: how can you patch if two different files will be opened, and you want to provide `read_data` content for both?

Comment: @Roelant: patch both. `patch()` can take a mock object to replace the target with, so create the mock first, then use `patch()` to replace two targets with the same object. Or, just create two mocks, as that might have benefits too (you can configure the mocks differently).

Answer (score 34):

In Python 3 you should use the decorator

```
@mock.patch("builtins.open", create=True)
```

or as context manager

```
with mock.patch('builtins.open', mock.mock_open(read_data=some_data)) as m:
    ...
```

Comment: This is simple, straight to the point and easy to understand and elegant.  Thank you.

Comment: What if you only want this to work when it tries to open a certain file?